# Combinatorics question about a dancing night

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

$n$ married couples came to a dancing club.

For a dance each woman picks a men **absolutely randomly**. What are the chances that none of the married couples dances together?

My attempt:

Clearly any matching between the men and women is equally likely and there are $n!$ possible matches. So if I knew the number of possible matches in which none of the couples dance together $\sigma_n$ the answer would be $\frac{\sigma_n}{n!}$. But I do not know $\sigma_n$.

$\sigma_k$ must satisfy the following equation:

$\sigma_k=k!-\sum_{j=1}^{j=k} \begin{pmatrix} k \\ j \end{pmatrix}\sigma_{k-j}$ with $\sigma_0=1, \sigma_1=0, \sigma_2=1$. Do not know how to proceed further.

Comment: I think that this is essentially the *Hat Check* problem, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29#Derangements) for more information. As the number $n$ tends to infinity, the probability approaches $\frac1e$.

Comment: Look up [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), it is a classic. There is plenty about them on this site. [Besides, your formulation is not very good. If all women choose a man randomly, chances are pretty slim that each man will be chosen by exactly one women.]